# New Windows 10 System, Moving Programs Between Monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a new Dell Precision workstation, using the internal monitor and 3 externals monitors.  When I move programs between monitors, I have a graphic pop up to make it "easier" to move between monitors.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to turn it off.  The graphic comes up with 4 blue boxes, 2 normal and one with dashed lines through it.  If the graphic loads, it looks like this:

[image]

The system is loaded with AMD graphics, and I'm using DisplayFusion Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the setting for anyone else having this issue.

Open Dell PremierColor and go to Display Splitter, and un-check Display Splitter on.  No more blue boxes when moving programs between monitors!

Comment: Just an FYI: after 48 hours, you can [accept your own answer](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer).